# Get text of multiple elements as separate values

Tags: jquery, node.js, web-scraping, web-crawler, cheerio

I'm trying to collect info from WEB, but if there is 2 elements in one page, info stored in same obj line. How to store info in different line? 
code:

```js
if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
  var $ = cheerio.load(html);
  $('#ctl00_MainContent_ipcAvaDay_upnlResultOutbound').each((e, el) => {
    var arrival_airport = $(el).find('.rowinfo2 td:nth-child(2)').text();
    var alio = [arrival_airport];
```

and the console.log im getting is

```
[RigaRiga]
```

instead of

```
[Riga]
[Riga]
```

maybe some ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `text()` is called on a collection of elements jQuery will concatenate all the values in to a single string.

If you want to create an array of all the separate values, use `map()`:

```
var arrival_airport = $(el).find('.rowinfo2 td:nth-child(2)').map(function() {
  return $(this).text();
}).get();
console.log(arrival_airport);
```

Comment: Good answer but we should probably stop using `this` in these blocks since most people have moved on to arrow functions and it will just cause confusion.

Comment: I'd argue that's not the case at all, especially since IE doesn't support arrow functions at all

Comment: Ok but consider that this is a cheerio question. This code runs in node.js, not in a browser.

Answer (score 1):

Just for clarity, avoiding `this` can be done in pre-ES6 as well as ES6 + arrow functions:

Pre-ES6 (no `this`):

```
var airports = $(el).find('.rowinfo2 td:nth-child(2)').map(function(i, el) {
  return $(el).text();
}).get();
```

ES6:

```
let airports = $(el).find('.rowinfo2 td:nth-child(2)').map((i, el) => $(el).text()).get()
```

Don't use `this` in these blocks because it's weird and it causes confusion.